# Uninstall not working for myapp created with install shield 2009

Tags: installshield, installshield-2009

I am using Install Shield 2009 for creating myapplication deployement. I added the uninstall.exe along with the deployement. But During uninstall my application is not closed automatically and the related dll and exe files are left back undeleted by uninstall.exe. how can i solve this issue? appreciate some help regarding this...or direction towards already existing query or something will be of great help...please reply asap....thanx in advance

Comment: What `uninstall.exe` are you talking about? InstallShield 2009 only creates setup.exe files (unless renamed), although they should handle both installation and uninstallation in either Basic MSI projects or InstallScript projects.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possible solutions:

1. Schedule FilesInUse dialog to be shown during uninstall
2. Create a custom action that will be executed only during the uninstall process and kill your application if it's already running.
3. For Windows Vista and upper versions one can use [Restart Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373524%28VS.85%29.aspx) to solve this problem.